# Car flip in crash while dragging

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

In some movies (Cars2), a driver would take a sharp turn while dragging the car and it would launch in air and flip.
Can this happen in real life?

If yes then what is the physics behind it?
Only friction acts on the car which passes through the axis of rotation, so what gives it the torque?
Can inertia produce torque?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need some materials, configurations, and energies that just aren't found in regular vehicles.  But there are vertical forces that can do this.

First you need a lot of energy.  That's handled by the forward motion of the vehicle.

Second, you need a wide wheelbase.  This provides a longer arc when tipping.

Finally, you need a lot of force from the road.  Tires coefficient of friction maxes out around 1.  This will need a lot more.  If you don't have magic tires, you'll need a curb or similar to provide a lot of force.

Now with the car moving at high speed, turn it so that it hits something grippy (magic tires/curb).

[image: Rotating Car]

As the car grips/strikes the curb, the curb supplies a force to oppose the motion.  But because it is so low on the car, this also creates a torque that tries to spin the car.

Initially, the weight of the car transfers to the leading edge.  But if the force is great enough, the normal force from the ground will no longer be sufficient to stop the spin.  The car will start to rotate.

As it rotates, the car pushes into the ground, so the normal force from the ground increases.  $N$ now exceeds the weight of the car and causes the center of mass to accelerate upward.  You can see in the diagram that the mass has risen.  If this acceleration is fast enough, the car will lift completely off the ground.

In any normal situation, the parts of a real car would deform, losing energy, making this much harder to do.  But you could probably get a die-cast car going fast enough for this to be possible.  Attempting it with regular tires on a flat road is just going to skid the tires.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This off topic, but how did you draw the figure

Comment: Just the drawing tools in google slides.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible due to the lack of air resistance and lift on the front(side) and bottom of the car. this is merely movie effects

Comment: Great answer, but you might wanna explain further how air resistance from your perspective affect the situation, the above answer isn't comprehensive enough and won't do any good to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

When a vehicle take a sharp turn like you propose, the velocity vector of the entire car is still in direction of the car's motion before the turn and as the vehicle drag, the net force on it is in the direction of the drag, but since the kinetic friction force isn't acting through the CG of the car, the car experiences torque due to the friction force and rolls around the CG. About the launching into the air, that's just an exaggerated special effect in movies (the only way a vehicle in a level ground could have launch significantly upward is if it hits a sort of ramp that channels some of it velocity vector upward), but in reality, the vehicle rolls and just bounce off the ground a bit due to some inherent elasticity in the vehicle structure. The inertia isn't causing torque since it's acting axially through the CG, but it's responsible for why the vehicle continues to roll multiple time even in the face of energy lose through the wrecking and friction etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best illustrated with a high vehicle:

[image: Car flips mechanics]

When a vehicle (car, bike, rocket etc) takes a turn, a force must act on it called the **[centripetal force](https://theory.uwinnipeg.ca/physics/circ/node6.html)** ($F_c$), in order to keep it on the circle:

$$F_c=\frac{m v^2}{R}$$

where $m$ is the vehicle's mass, $v$ its speed and $R$ the radius of the circle.
For a road vehicle this force is provided by the friction forces $F_f$ between the tires and the road surface.

However, if the required $F_c$ is very high, the torque of $F_f$ about the centre of gravity (CoG) can be enough to topple the vehicle. Kinetic energy may cause it to roll a few turns.

High $F_c$ is obviously needed for high $m$, high $v$ and low $R$ (sharp turns). The said torque, all things being equal, is lower for low lying cars (which in part explains why racing cars are mainly low lying).

This mechanism could not launch the vehicle in the air: that requires a ramp of an added studio effect.